# Spring handler mappings in Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

I'm having trouble getting a simple Spring example to work, Spring version 4.1.7.RELEASE.

web.xml:

```
<web-app id="epw" version="2.5" 
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

  <display-name>EPW</display-name>

  <servlet>
      <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
      <!-- Doesn't seem to help
      <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/epw-config.xml WEB-INF/SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
      </init-param>
      -->      
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/epw/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

  <!-- Doesn't seem to help
  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/epw-config.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  -->

</web-app>
```

SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.1.xsd">    

    <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="g.n.h.a.b.e"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
        <property name="prefix" value="/templates/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".html"/>
    </bean>        

</beans>
```

DemoController.java:

```
package g.n.h.a.b.e;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="/epw")
public class DemoController {

    public DemoController() {
        log.info("created");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/foo", method=RequestMethod.GET, produces="text/plain")
    public String foo(@RequestParam(value="name", required=false, defaultValue="bar") final String name, Model model, final HttpServletRequest request) {
        log.entry();
        String view = "foo" ;
        try {
            model.addAttribute("name", name);
            return view ;
        } finally {
            log.exit(view);
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping(value="/riddle", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doRiddle(Model model) {
        log.entry();
        String view = "foo";
        ModelAndView mav = null ;
        try {
            model.addAttribute("name", "riddle");
            mav = new ModelAndView(view, null, model) ;
            return mav ;
        } finally {
            log.exit(mav) ;
        }
    }

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger() ;  

}
```

WAR contents:

C:\projects\bne_main\JavaProjects\webApps\epw>jar tf target\epw.war

```
META-INF/
META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
WEB-INF/
WEB-INF/classes/
WEB-INF/classes/g/
WEB-INF/classes/g/n/
WEB-INF/classes/g/n/h/
WEB-INF/classes/g/n/h/a/
WEB-INF/classes/g/n/h/a/b/
WEB-INF/classes/g/n/h/a/b/e/
WEB-INF/classes/templates/
WEB-INF/lib/
index.html
WEB-INF/classes/g/n/h/a/b/e/DemoController.class
WEB-INF/classes/log4j.xml
WEB-INF/classes/log4j2.xml
WEB-INF/classes/revision.class
WEB-INF/classes/revision.properties
WEB-INF/classes/templates/foo.html
WEB-INF/epw-config.xml
WEB-INF/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar
WEB-INF/lib/commons-logging-1.2.jar
WEB-INF/lib/groovy-all-2.4.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/javassist-3.16.1-GA.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.3.jar
WEB-INF/lib/ognl-3.0.8.jar
WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-aop-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-beans-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-context-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-core-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-expression-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-jdbc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-tx-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-web-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/spring-webmvc-4.1.7.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/thymeleaf-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/lib/unbescape-1.1.0.RELEASE.jar
WEB-INF/SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml
WEB-INF/web.xml
META-INF/maven/g.n.h.a.b/e/pom.xml
META-INF/maven/g.n.h.a.b/e/pom.properties
META-INF/INDEX.LIST
```

According to deployment log, `/epw/riddle` and `/epw/foo` are both mapped:

```
21-Jul-2015 11:59:00.054 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive C:\tomcat-8.0.24\webapps\epw.war
21-Jul-2015 11:59:01.568 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
21-Jul-2015 11:59:01.677 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher': initialization started
21-Jul-2015 11:59:01.708 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext.prepareRefresh Refreshing WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jul 21 11:59:01 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
21-Jul-2015 11:59:01.755 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/SpringDispatcher-servlet.xml]
21-Jul-2015 11:59:02.176 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/epw/riddle],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView gov.ny.health.adsg.bne.epw.DemoController.doRiddle(org.springframework.ui.Model)
21-Jul-2015 11:59:02.176 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.registerHandlerMethod Mapped "{[/epw/foo],methods=[GET],produces=[text/plain]}" onto public java.lang.String gov.ny.health.adsg.bne.epw.DemoController.foo(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
21-Jul-2015 11:59:02.254 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jul 21 11:59:01 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
21-Jul-2015 11:59:02.301 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.initControllerAdviceCache Looking for @ControllerAdvice: WebApplicationContext for namespace 'SpringDispatcher-servlet': startup date [Tue Jul 21 11:59:01 EDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
21-Jul-2015 11:59:02.691 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.initServletBean FrameworkServlet 'SpringDispatcher': initialization completed in 1014 ms
21-Jul-2015 11:59:02.691 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-94] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive C:\tomcat-8.0.24\webapps\epw.war has finished in 2,637 ms
```

At runtime, `localhost:8080/epw/` shows `index.html`, as expected. However, both `localhost:8080/epw/foo` and `localhost:8080/epw/riddle` return 404 with nothing further in logs.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried `localhost:8080/epw/epw/epw/foo` ? (not joking)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your dispatcher servlet is mapped to the context path of /epw here (web.xml):

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/epw/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

This means, that your application should respond under `localhost:8080/epw/epw/foo` and not `localhost:8080/epw/foo`. Could you try either changing the servlet mapping, or removing the @RequestMapping annotation from your controller.

Comment: Thanks for comment. I have tried many combinations like `localhost:8080/epw/epw/foo`, `localhost:8080/foo`, etc, without success. Here's what I got this time: `21-Jul-2015 13:28:49.948 WARNING [http-nio-8080-exec-104] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/epw/epw/foo] in DispatcherServlet with name 'SpringDispatcher'`

Comment: On the other hand, `localhost:8080/epw/x/foo` just gets 404 without any log entry.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the url, that you are hitting through any link, or any click action through jquery, it is being appended with the context url along with your url mapping in the controller. Like in my case I populated a datatable through jquery and on each row of the table I have bind a click action that is redrecting to let say url "/projects";
and then I reallized that I missed my context url in the same and then chagned the mapping with "/context_url/projects".

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

Model value can be directly used in the view, passing it through ModelAndView constructor is not required.

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/riddle", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView doRiddle(Model model) {
        log.entry();
        String view = "foo";
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(view);
        try {
         model.addAttribute("name", "riddle");
         return mav ;
        } finally {
        log.exit(mav) ;
     }
}
```